# Table data to be used in sql string based on specific table row

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have php script that query's my database and pulls the data based on `acceptance` field value.

```
SELECT * from database WHERE acceptance = 1
```

This works well. My PHP script then loops through the returned object populating a table

**Booking ID       Accept         Decline**

```
123          Yes     No
```

Where the `Yes/No` string is above, there are clickable icons that talk to a JavaScript function.

So my question, I need to have an ajax call so once the user clicks the accepted icon the JavaScrip will take the booking id and use this in the update query dynamically

```
UPDATE accepted in Bookings Where userid = $clickedRowData
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I hope, you don't use two separate fields `Accept` and `Decline`.

Comment: Have look here, https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/ for sending ajax requests.

Comment: I have used two sperate fields, one so it can be declinded and one so it can be accepted! ??

http://s24.postimg.org/5t7xa3lit/edit.png << if that helps

Answer (score 0):

As you have asked given code to call ajax on the click of td you can call ajax and update data as you wants.

You have not give all columns real name so i have assumed column names.
Here is Javascript Code:-

```
$("table tr td").click(function(){
  $.ajax({url:"ajax.php",type:"POST",data:{booking_id:123,"booking":1}});
});
```

Here is 
Php Code :-

```
if($_POST["booking"]){
//UPDATE accepted set Bookings=1 Where booking_id =  $_POST["booking_id"]'
}
else{
 //UPDATE accepted set Bookings=1 Where booking_id =    $_POST["booking_id"]'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, Its not the table i want to click, its an icon in the table that i want to click, once the icon has been clicked ( there is an icon in every row ) i want the booking id data of that specific table row to be pushed into a string variable so i can add it to a string to query a DB i can do all the AJAX and php stuff im just confused at how i would get the booking id

http://s24.postimg.org/5t7xa3lit/edit.png

I hope that link makes sense

Comment: Hmmm , Its look like you need to assign attributes in html table so by on that click . You can check value and on that you can update data. I have done like these tables earlier.

Comment: how would i do that then ??